# `Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Unmanaged<CGEvent>?'` - but docs say NULL is allowed?

Tags: swift

I think this should be a relatively easy problem to solve, I'm just not familiar enough with Swift... I am creating an active event tap which filters out keypress events. However I am getting the following error.

```
main.swift:31:20: error: cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Unmanaged<CGEvent>?'
            return NULL
```

What confuses me however is the docs of [CGEventTapCallBack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgeventtapcallback) say:

> If the event tap is an active filter, your callback function should return one of the following:
>
> - The (possibly modified) event that is passed in. This event is passed back to the event system.
> - A  newly-constructed event. After the new event has been passed back to the event system, the new event will be released along with the original event.
> - **NULL if the event passed in is to be deleted.**

As far as I can tell I am passing NULL to delete the event, why is Swift reporting this as an error?

```
import var Darwin.C.NULL
import Foundation

func myCGEventTapCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    if [.keyDown , .keyUp].contains(type) {
        var keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode) //CGKeyCode
        if(haltPropogation(key: keyCode, isDown: type == .keyDown)){
            return NULL
        }
    }
    return Unmanaged.passRetained(event)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried returning `nil`?

Comment: @LeoDabus That did it alright! Thanks! :) Or at least, it compiles, which is good. Hope it functions correctly.

Comment: @LeoDabus can confirm returning nil fully resolves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @LeoDabus specified in the comments, the correct approach is returning `nil`:

```
import var Darwin.C.NULL
import Foundation

func myCGEventTapCallback(proxy: CGEventTapProxy, type: CGEventType, event: CGEvent, refcon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) -> Unmanaged<CGEvent>? {
    if [.keyDown , .keyUp].contains(type) {
        var keyCode = event.getIntegerValueField(.keyboardEventKeycode) //CGKeyCode
        if(haltPropogation(key: keyCode, isDown: type == .keyDown)){
            return nil
        }
    }
    return Unmanaged.passUnretained(event)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `passUnretained`?

Comment: @Rick Thanks, you're right it should indeed be `passUnretained`! :)